# Was it usual for "Society" to be written with an initial capital?

Tags: edgar-wallace, the-just-men-of-cordova, orthography

From [chapter 9 of *The Just Men of Cordova*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Just_Men_of_Cordova/Chapter_9) (1917) by Edgar Wallace:

> The Earl of Verlond was a stickler for punctuality: a grim, bent old man, with a face that, so **Society** said, told eloquently the story of his life, his bitter tongue was sufficient to maintain for him the respect—or if not the respect, the fear that so ably substitutes respect—of his friends.

I think that "Society" refers here to "rich and fashionable people".

Was it usual for "Society" to be written with an initial capital? or does it mean certain society?

Comment: It was certainly common for Society (and similar nouns) to be written in capital letters in the early 19th century. It was less common by 1917.